How do I configure Scrapy to save logs to AWS S3?
I am currently using this setup to save logs to the directory where Scrapy is placed.
    class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        ...
        ts = time.time()
        date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
        d = date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")
        custom_settings = {
            'LOG_FILE': f'logs/{d}_{name}.log',
            'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
                ...
            }
    
        }

The var name is take from the database.
Because the log files are getting bigger, I would like to store them outside of the server where Scrapy is running.
I am already having integrated AWS S3 for storing the files that I scrape - this setup is in the file settings.py and it's working well - specifically, I have this setup to integrated S3:
    IMAGES_STORE = "..."
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ",,,"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
    AWS_ENDPOINT_URL = '...'
    AWS_REGION_NAME = "..."
    AWS_USE_SSL = True
    AWS_VERIFY = True
    IMAGES_STORE_S3_ACL = 'public-read'

But I struggle to find out how to properly set to logs to be saved on AWS S3.
Any advise will be appreciated.
